# Call function in mvc razor view from shared layout using relative path i.e. _layout.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Is it possible to call a function that declared in _layout.cshtml file and to access it in child views using relative path?

My function in _layout.cshtml

```
   @functions{

    public static string SampleFunction(string temp)
    {
        string sample=temp;
        return sample;
    }
}
```

and I call it from may child view like

```
@Html.Raw(MyDirectory_MyApp_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.SampleFunction("Test"))
```

but I want to call it using relative path like

```
@Html.Raw("~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml...") // My function blah blah blah
```

It works fine when I declare and call function in view, but I want to make it generic for all views that is why I placed it in master page i.e. _Layout.cshtml

Comment: Short answer is no (and using `@Html.Raw(..)` makes no sense). Create a static method in your project, not the view, and call it in the view (or better, use a view model that includes a property for the result of your method, and call in in the GET method before you pass the model to the view)

Comment: Never use `@Html.Raw` for referencing resource by its path like `@Url.Content`, it should only used for returning unencoded string. Move your static method outside view page and assign string properties from that method (don't forget to return viewmodel together with corresponding view).

Comment: I think you should reconsider your approach. Razor is not a good place to define re-usable utility functions. Even if you could get it to work, it's really not what these templates are meant for. You should instead define your function in a C# class, where you can access it from all your templates.

Comment: OK I will change my flow and move it to BLL layer and it works fine for all views. Thanks to all for guidelines